# using var save xml tag data in to xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose my xml file

`sample.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <api>
    <category>
       <id>1</id>
       <title>title-1</title>
       <mode />
    </category> 
    <category>
       <id>2</id>
       <title>title-2</title>
       <mode />
    </category>
    <category> 
       <id>3</id>
       <title>title-3</title>
       <!--store mode tag in xml-->
         <mode>
            <title>title-mod-1</title>        
            <id>mod-id</id>
            <description>my own description</description>
         </mode>

       <!--end of mode tag-->
    </category>
 </api>
```

My Ajax call method

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "sample.xml",
   contentType: "text/xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   data: "",
   crossDomain:true,
   success: function(xml) { 

     $(xml).find('category').each(function(){

        var id=$(this).find('id').text();                                
        var title=$(this).find('title').text();
                    alert(id + ""+title);                   //good

                    var my_mode= $(this).find('mode').text();  
                    alert(my_mode); 
                     /* using this alert output some like that
                     title-mod-1
                     mod-id
                     my own description
                     */     

                    /* but i require my output something like that
                   </mode>
                     <title>title-mod-1</title>        
                     <id>mod-id</id>
                     <description>my own description</description>
                   </mode>

                   above output is store in xml file(modified.xml)  in one variable and 
                   able to use this xml file 
                      */
                   /*for those <mode /> have not any thing then nothing will be save*/                          
        });
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "sample.xml",
   contentType: "text/xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   data: "",
   crossDomain:true,
   success: function(xml) { 

     $(xml).find('category').each(function(){

        var id=$(this).find('id').text();                                
        var title=$(this).find('title').text();
                    alert(id + ""+title);                   //good

                    var my_mode= $(this).find('mode').html(); //try this
                  // var my_mode= $(this).find('mode').parent().html(); //or try this
                    alert(my_mode); 
                     /* using this alert output some like that
                     title-mod-1
                     mod-id
                     my own description
                     */     

                    /* but i require my output something like that
                   </mode>
                     <title>title-mod-1</title>        
                     <id>mod-id</id>
                     <description>my own description</description>
                   </mode>

                   above output is store in xml file(modified.xml)  in one variable and 
                   able to use this xml file 
                      */
                   /*for those <mode /> have not any thing then nothing will be save*/                          
        });
              });
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjzvq/)

Comment: Thanks for your response But method are not working.
 var my_mode= $(this).find('mode').html(); //try this
 var my_mode= $(this).find('mode').parent().html();

Comment: have u used the code i have given. what it says if not working?

Comment: actually i am using this same code in phonegap for native application development. when i am calling this ajax then it is showing error something like that

"Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method ......."